# An error occurred (InvalidLambdaResponseException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: Unrecognizable lambda output

Tags: javascript, python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

Am new to aws development and was trying to do password less features using aws cognito's Custom Auth Flow, lambda triggers and the aws python SDK.

My problem is after the call to **InitiateAuth**, I always get the error below:

`An error occurred (InvalidLambdaResponseException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: Unrecognizable lambda output`

Full traceback is:

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_custom_auth.py", line 52, in <module>
    ClientId=client_id
  File "/Users/jules/Repositories/snaaap/onemac-api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 320, in _api_call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name, kwargs)
  File "/Users/jules/Repositories/snaaap/onemac-api/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/botocore/client.py", line 623, in _make_api_call
    raise error_class(parsed_response, operation_name)
botocore.errorfactory.InvalidLambdaResponseException: An error occurred (InvalidLambdaResponseException) when calling the InitiateAuth operation: Unrecognizable lambda output`

I can see thru cloudwatch logs that the **defineAuthChallenge Trigger** and **createAuthChallenge Trigger** calls are successful and was even able to print out logs to verify this.

I did the lambda functions first with **Javascript**, then with **Python**, just to try another method.

I tried to return the following in python (I am editing using the lambda editor console)

- `return event`
- `result = {
          "isBase64Encoded": False,
          "statusCode": 200,
          "headers": {},
          "body": json.dumps(event)
      } 
  return result`

I tried to return the following in javascript (I am editing using the lambda editor console)

- `context.succeed(event)`
- `callback(null, event)`
- `context.done(event)`
- `context.done(JSON.stringify(event))`

And permutations of those mentioned above, but I still kept on getting the error :( Appreciate anyone that can help!

**EDIT**

Performed another request:

Below are the logs from **defineAuthChallenge**:

`START RequestId: 14441740-cc65-11e8-a632-9508cbba464c Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 14441740-cc65-11e8-a632-9508cbba464c
REPORT RequestId: 14441740-cc65-11e8-a632-9508cbba464c  Duration: 6.70 ms   Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 20 MB`

Below are the logs from **createAuthChallenge **:

`START RequestId: 144995b6-cc65-11e8-8d2d-5388c84ccf95 Version: $LATEST
END RequestId: 144995b6-cc65-11e8-8d2d-5388c84ccf95
REPORT RequestId: 144995b6-cc65-11e8-8d2d-5388c84ccf95  Duration: 592.59 ms Billed Duration: 600 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 29 MB`

Comment: The problem is most likely to be in your reponses to the `CreateAuthChallenge`, `DefineAuthChallenge` or `VerifyAuthChallengeResponse` lambdas. Can you include a log of what you're returning from those lambda functions please?

Comment: Hi @thomasmichaelwallace, thanks! I provided the logs from cloudwatch in the edit portion. There isn't yet any from VerifyAuthChallenge since I haven't yet submitted a challenge answer -- I couldn't because of the error above. I can't send the session back.

Comment: Sorry- I wasn't clear enough- I want to see the JSON that you're returning from those lambdas, for example I'm expecting `CreateAuthChallenge` to return something like: `{ response: {
        publicChallengeParameters: {},
        privateChallengeParameters: { something: 'else' },
        challengeMetadata: 'meta',
      } }`.

Comment: Hi @thomasmichaelwallace, solved it! Thanks for the tip! I was about to post an edit, but I re-scanned everything and saw a post here https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=237677, saying that if any of the keys are wrong in the response attribute then lambda would return that error. Changed `challengeMetaData` to `challengeMetadata`. It worked. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

Changed `challengeMetaData` to `challengeMetadata` in the response I am returning from my **createAuthChallenge** function. Learned that when you put an invalid key in the response attribute lambda will throw the `InvalidLambdaResponseException`, though I hope next time cloudwatch can catch it.

Got an idea from @thomasmichaelwallace, and this article https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=237677.